# How to format multi line data in single line but separated by comma using sed?

Tags: sed

How to format below output in linux using sed

Output

```
[
        "iqn.1998-01.com.vmware:vm-1-20713dc0",
        "iqn.1998-01.com.vmware:vm-2-48e366a4",
        "iqn.1998-01.com.vmware:vm-3-7ee56a9c"
]
```

I am looking for this in single line as below
Expected output— ( this list may vary  since its dynamic output may be one or more than one)

```
iqn.1998-01.com.vmware:vm-1-20713dc0,iqn.1998-01.com.vmware:vm-2-48e366a4,iqn.1998-01.com.vmware:vm-3-7ee56a9c
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this a JSON content? Why use `sed`? Can you use a JSON aware parser like `jq`?

Comment: Yes I can use jq but dont know the syntax to do this..

Comment: You just need to join the contents by `,` - `jq -r 'join(",")'`

Comment: just for your information this output is task stdout...

Comment: Just pipe the result of task stdout to the above `jq` filter `cmd | jq -r 'join(",")'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the sed this how i have done and which works for me.

```
shell: echo "{{ iqn_list.stdout_lines | to_json }}" | sed 's/[][]//g' | sed "s/'/ /g" | sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' | sed 's/^ *//g' | sed 's/ *//g'
```